# wave equation with $H^{-1}$ source

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, hyperbolic-pde, wave-equation

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary and given $f \in H^{-1}((0,T)\times \Omega)$, consider the wave equation
$$ \Box u =f\quad \text{on $(0,T)\times \Omega$},$$
with $u|_{(0,T)\times \partial \Omega}=0$ and $u(0,x)=\partial_t u(0,x)=0$ on $\Omega$.

Does this problem admit a unique solution in the energy space
$$ u \in C(0,T;L^2(\Omega))\cap C^1(0,T;H^{-1}(\Omega)).$$